# convert dataframe of Lat, Lon, and measurements into spatial grid

Tags: r

I have a data.frame that looks like this for example:

```
> head(dat)
  YEAR DAY      LAT       LON BIOMASS
 2000   8 39.78333 -73.33333    32.7
 2000   8 39.86667 -73.46667     6.8
 2001   7 40.10000 -73.15000     9.5
 2001   7 40.23333 -72.73333    11.3
 2001   8 40.25000 -73.26667     3.2
 2002   7 40.41667 -72.73333   159.7
```

I want to convert this data into a series of 2D matrices (LAT x LON) of BIOMASS for each day-year combination.  I want the grid resolution to be by 0.10 degree.  I know that in some cases there would be more than one observation in a grid.  And in those cases, I would take the mean of the overlapping values.  Additionally there would be many grid points with no associated value, for these I would like to insert NA.

My actual date.frame is quite large (50 years and about 25 days per year) so I need something that is efficient.  I tried to find a package in R that would do this but no luck.  Does anyone have experience doing this sort of thing?  I could use Matlab though I am much more comfortable in R.

Comment: it seems a little unclear to me, you would group year/day/lat/lon if both of the last two are within .10 degrees? or group regardless if they fall in the same year,day? You could also give an example a little bit bigger that shows some expected results

Comment: @erasmortg  it would be a new matrix of Lat x Lon for each year/day.  And each row/column of the matrix represents the Biomass values within a 0.10 degree interval.  Make better sense?

Comment: Could you update your post with an expected data frame from the same values in your head(dat)? That would be simpler to reverse engineer I believe